# Fastest & most efficient way to remove lines containing strings (strings listed in another text file)

Tags: text-processing

I was wondering if fgrep is the fastest and most efficient way to remove lines from a file (file1) that contain a string found in another file (file2).

I have found the function fgrep that should do this as follows:

```
  fgrep -v -f file1  file2  > file_with_lines_containing_search_strings_removed
```

I don't know if this will work well with very large files.

I have two files with 100,000s of lines and I want to use the fastest method possible.

Thanks.

Happy July 4th to all those funny looking Americans.

Comment: You want to use the `-F` option, see JJoao's answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want "lines that contain a string found in another file"
(and not "lines that contain a string that match a regExp in another file"), try:

```
grep -vFf file1 file2 > file3
```

"grep -F" is not looking for regexp match but simple string match (**much faster**)

or even better

```
grep -vwFf file1 file2                 #respect word boundary
```

#### Just a quick time comparation test:

1) build a 100 000 random lines example file2

```
seq 1000000 | shuf -n 100000 > file2
```

2) build a 10 000 random lines example file1 (strings to remove)

```
 seq 1000000 | shuf -n 10000 > file1
```

31) Using `grep -F`  --- `time grep -vwFf file1 file2 > file31`

```
real    0m0.111s
user    0m0.100s
sys 0m0.008s
```

32) Without `-F` --- `time grep -vwf file1 file2 > file32`

... hours!

```
if file1 has just 300 lines --    0.327s          very fast
....              600 lines --    8.326s
....              900 lines --   35.334s
....             1200 lines -- 1m31.433s      (quadratic with file1 len?)

....            10000 lines -- it is still calculating (several hours?)
UPDATED                     1h03m53.983s
```

#### Conclusion of the test:

- `grep -vFf file1 file2`is much faster than `grep -vf`
- `grep -vFf file1 file2` has no problems with big `file1` files
- `grep -vf file1 file2` is evilly affected with the increase of the size of `file1` file (this is only visible for sizes  > 500 lines or > 4kbytes)

Comment: And without `-F` `grep` may consume very large amounts of memory.  `-F` was so fast I doubted it worked…

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will be fine. The worst case is when the file with the strings to exclude is equal to the size of the file being processed, and of a size that doesn't fit into memory. If you have that case then split the exclusion file into chunks and run multiple passes.